# Deeplinking needed for mobile app in salesforce

Tags: community, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, salesforce-sdk-android

We are using salesforce customer community where we implemented custom login and custom change password screen. We are using android native mobile application with backend of salesforce customer community. Our requirement is to send a Link to customer for change the password via email, once customer click on that link in email then it should launch the mobile app with change password screen (lightning component in salesforce).

Do we have any specific parameter which needs to pass to mobile app when we launch it to open a mobile app with a screen with same user context.